# MainProcess in logging's format %process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I configure my logging as

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(process)d-%(processName)s-  %(message)s')
logging.debug("Start of program")

def factorial(n):
    logging.debug('Start of factorial(%s)' %(n))
    total = 1
    for i in range(n+1):
        total *= i 
        logging.debug('i is ' + str(i) + ', toal is ' + str(total))
    logging.debug('End of factorial(%s)' %(n))
    return total 
print(factorial(10))
logging.debug("End of program")
```

Plan to trace the processName and processID,
Unfortunately, It provide few helpful info

```
$ python py_logging.py 
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  Start of program
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  Start of factorial(10)
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 0, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 1, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 2, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 3, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 4, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 5, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 6, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 7, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 8, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 9, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  i is 10, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  End of factorial(10)
0
2019-03-20 23:11:15,014-DEBUG-12876-MainProcess-  End of program
```

What does the MainProcess mean ?which does not expose any info

I assume such a structure might be helpful

```
2019-03-20 23:18:47,447-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  Start of program
systemd,1 splash
  `-systemd,2122 --user
      `-code,3521
          `-code,3539
              `-code,3691
                  `-bash,16025
                      `-python,16076 py_logging.py
                          `-sh,16077 -c pstree -asp 16076
                              `-pstree,16078 -asp 16076

2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  Start of factorial(10)
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 0, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 1, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 2, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 3, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 4, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 5, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 6, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 7, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 8, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 9, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,493-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  i is 10, toal is 0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,494-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  End of factorial(10)
0
2019-03-20 23:18:47,494-DEBUG-16076-MainProcess-  End of program
```

How could I understand the MainProcess, main to what?

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes, it is the process name (if available), what is the name of you main program (the one with id 16076 ) , if you want to display the python module name, try %(module)s

Comment: It seems it is the process name when you use the multiprocessing module ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `processName` attribute is retrieved with `multiprocessing.current_process().name`. This is `"MainProcess"` for the main process (which is all you'll have if you don't use the `multiprocessing` module). For child processes started by `multiprocessing`, the name for a new process can be specified when you create a `Process` object, and by default it will be "Process" followed by some numbers which depend on how many children you've spawned.